# jQuery - Find specific class and remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, frontend

I want to find a specific div with the class **.factive** and remove it, to add it to another div.

Here is my current code:

```
$('.factive').removeClass('.factive');
```

I know it does find the div I want (checked via Javascript Console), but it doesn't remove the class.

Any clues?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There's no `.` in the actual class name, only in the selector.

```
$('.factive').removeClass('factive');
```

That will effectively remove the class `factive` from all elements that have it.